# bash--instersection of two files based on a specific columns?

Tags: bash, file, intersection

I want to do the following and would really appreciate if someone can help me accomplish this:

I have 2 tab-delim files named File1.txt and File2.txt(shown below). 
If the 2nd column (integer) in File1.txt is found in 3rd column (integer) of File2.txt then
i want to make new_File1.txt and new_File2.txt and keep appending
the rows.

**File1.txt:**

```
1   80  xyc
1   304 xyv
1   813653  xyb
1   813661  xyn
1   954653  xym
```

**File2.txt:**

```
abvb    1   178
aaa 1   304 
ttt 1   353
ggg 1   98971
ghj 1   813653
```

So for example my new_File1.txt will look like:

**new_File1.txt:**

```
1   304 xyv
1   813653  xyb
```

**new_File2.txt:**

```
aaa     1   304
ghj     1   813653
```

Thank you all for your help!
I have used :

```
join -1 2 -2 3 -t '\t' file1.txt file2.txt
```

but it gives me the following output:

```
\1      80      xyc\abvb        1       178
\1      80      xyc\aaa 1       304
\1      80      xyc\ttt 1       353
\1      80      xyc\ggg 1       98971
\1      80      xyc\ghj 1       813653
\1      304     xyv\abvb        1       178
\1      304     xyv\aaa 1       304
\1      304     xyv\ttt 1       353
\1      304     xyv\ggg 1       98971
\1      304     xyv\ghj 1       813653
\1      813653  xyb\abvb        1       178
\1      813653  xyb\aaa 1       304
\1      813653  xyb\ttt 1       353
\1      813653  xyb\ggg 1       98971
\1      813653  xyb\ghj 1       813653
\1      813661  xyn\abvb        1       178
\1      813661  xyn\aaa 1       304
\1      813661  xyn\ttt 1       353
\1      813661  xyn\ggg 1       98971
\1      813661  xyn\ghj 1       813653
\1      954653  xym\abvb        1       178
\1      954653  xym\aaa 1       304
\1      954653  xym\ttt 1       353
\1      954653  xym\ggg 1       98971
\1      954653  xym\ghj 1       813653
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`join(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join).